# Why does AJAX update in Primefaces 5.3 works

Tags: primefaces

I was using Primefaces 5.0 and when I updated a p:selectCheckboxMenu with AJAX, it stopped working. After some research I came to understand that its listeners were broken because the HTML DOM tree was injected with new HTML components (returned in the AJAX response) and, because ready() was not reinvoked, the listeners were not reattached.

When I upgraded to Primefaces 5.3 (using the same code) the AJAX update started working.

I thought that they replaced
$(selector).on(event,function) {...} with $(document).on(event,selector,function) {...}, binding the listeners to the document instead of the components... but they kept the $(selector).on(event,function) {...} approach!

Any ideas on how they solved that problem? How are the listeners attached to new components then?

Comment: Most likely by simply re-executing the full javascript for the component and having the call to do that IN the response.

Comment: In both versions the refresh function (AJAX response) of the PrimeFaces.widget.SelectCheckboxMenu removes the component from DOM, its data and listeners and reexecute the init function (creates component and bind events). That was already being done in Primefaces 5.0! The only difference that I caught was that the component ID started being escaped but I wanted to make sure that was the bug or if it was something else. Unfortunately I can't change primefaces.js to try the Primefaces 5.0 js file with the component escaped ID

Comment: You can override individual functions. Maybe worth a try?

Comment: `PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.refresh` in core.js? `PrimeFaces.createWidget` calls it.

Comment: No, refresh in primefaces.js. Refresh in core.js seems to be doing the same thing in both versions, only the code is more elegant in the latest. I'm going to explore the override suggestion. Thank you both.

Comment: core.js is an actual source. primefaces.js is a minified and combined version or core.js and all the other sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update is working because of the escaped client ID. After overriding the refresh function, as suggested by @Kukeltje, I could test it.
The PrimeFaces.escapeClientId function it’s a js function to replace the colon “:” with double backslashes. Thanks to this correction, the AJAX update in Primefaces 5.3 works correctly!

For testing purposes, I overrided the refresh function of the SelectCheckboxMenu, added a print just to make sure it was being called and replaced the 5.3 refresh with the 5.0 refresh.

```
PrimeFaces.widget.SelectCheckboxMenu.prototype.refresh = function(a) {
        console.log('method overriden!');
        $(this.panelId).remove();
        this.init(a)
}
```

As suspected, the refresh stopped working, confirming that the ID was not being escaped before!